# Academic Gowns and Hood Colours for Overseas Students Where the University Does Not Have One

Tags: united-kingdom, academic-dress

My university has asked me (actually, a friend) to process in a graduation ceremony, and expects me to wear full academic dress. However, my home country and home university does not have an academic dress.

Is there a standard hood colour in the UK which means "master's degree; overseas university (unspecified)"? And indeed the same for a bachelor's / doctorate degree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ask the university. There will be administrative offices and a secretariat of some kind, and they will be **delighted** to be able to help. It is a lot more interesting than most of the stuff they find themselves having to do.

The general rule is to wear the gown and hood corresponding to this university's equivalent degree if there is one, so if you are a masters *student* then presumably you will have a bachelor's *degree* and so the B.A. dress would be appropriate. But ask them, and they will happily tell you.